# Coin tossing simulator that prints a chart of # of tosses vs heads and tails (Java)

Tags: java, simulation

so im doing a problem that requires me to simulate coin toss with math.random. Ive built a method to count the amount of times a coin lands on heads and lands on tails using an array, but now i need to print out a table in the form :

number of tosses-----heads-----tails

10
.

.

.

1000000

How do I go about doing all this? Any tips would be appreciated. Here is my code at the moment:

```
 public static void main(String[]args){
    int[] Coin_Toss = {0,0};
    
   
  
    int flip1 = 10;
   /* int flip2 = 100;
    int flip3 = 1000;
    int flip3 = 10000;
    int flip4 = 100000;
    int flip5 = 1000000; */

   


   for(int i = 0; i < flip1; i++)// Tallys coin flips into array for Flip ;
   { 
    Toss(Coin_Toss);
   
   }
  

   System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s","# of Tosses","# of Heads","# of Tails");
  for(int i = 0; i< 1; i++) // Print out tallied array
  {
      System.out.printf("\n%d\t\t%d\t\t%d",flip1,Coin_Toss[0],Coin_Toss[1]);
  }

}


public static int Toss(int[] a){// method to simulated coin toss
   
    int num = (int)(Math.random()*2);
    if (num == 0){
        a[0]++;

    }
    else{
        a[1]++;
    }
    
    return num;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should make an array or ArrayList.

Comment: What is the purpose of `int num = (int)(Math.random()*2);`? I doubt it simulates a coin tossing as `x *2 ` is never odd.

Comment: Math.random returns a double [0-1) so multiplying it by 2 and changing it to in will give me a range of [0-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you are doing one thing wrong (even it works):

Is pass the object `Coin_Toss` and using it in every iteration. It works because you update the reference memory but is not a good practice.

If I've understand well you want something like that

```
//Iterate through nFlips (10, 100, 1000 ... )

//Calculate how many times is head or tail

//print
```

So at this point you need:

1. Store the iteration you have done
2. Store the result (head or tail)

There are many ways. You could have an Object with attributes `nIterations`, `nHead`, `nTail` to store the data, for example.

But, following your work I think this is a better solution

```
//Total flips you want to do
int[] flips = { 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 };

//List where store the results
List<int[]> results = new ArrayList<int[]>();

//Loop the 'nIterations'
for (int i = 0; i < flips.length; i++) {    
    results.add(Toss(flips[i])); //<-- call method to get the results and store in ArrayList
}
//Print the result
System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s", "# of Tosses", "# of Heads", "# of Tails");
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) // Print out tallied array
{
    System.out.printf("\n%d\t\t%d\t\t%d", flips[i], results.get(i)[0], results.get(i)[1]);
}
```

And the method who flip the coin is something as follow

```
public static int[] Toss(int nIterations) {// method to simulated coin toss
    //At this point is better create an object and return that instead of use the same one
    int[] coinValues = {0, 0};
    for(int i = 0; i < nIterations; i++) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        if (num == 0) {
            coinValues[0]++;
        } else {
            coinValues[1]++;
        }
    }   
    return coinValues;
}
```

And that's all.

As an overview: You have one 'principal' list to store the data. That list is compound by integer arrays with two positions (first head, second tails).
So iterating that you have every data you need.

I edit to add the console output

```
# of Tosses # of Heads  # of Tails
10          6           4
100         41          59
1000        503         497
10000       5015        4985
100000      49931       50069
1000000     499940      500060
```